# What is the difference between these two programs which compute triangular numbers?

Tags: c, for-loop, math, cs50

Both of these codes compile, but only the second one does what I want it to.
First Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()

  {
    int TriNumber = 0;
    int n;

       for(n = 5;  n <= 50; n += 5)
       TriNumber = ((n + 1) * n) / 2;

        printf("The trianglular number of %d is %d\n", n, TriNumber);

   }
```

Which outputs:

> The trianglular number of 55 is 1275

The below program does what I want it to: it prints the triangular number for every fifth integer between 5 and 50.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()

{
   int TriNumber = 0;
   int n;

    for(n = 5;  n <= 50; n += 5)

        printf("The trianglular number of %d is %d\n", n, TriNumber = (((n + 1) * n) / 2));

}
```

Which gives my desired output:

> The trianglular number of 5 is 15 
>   
>  The trianglular number of 10 is 55
>   
>  The trianglular number of 15 is 120
>   
>  The trianglular number of 20 is 210
>   
>  The trianglular number of 25 is 325
>   
>  The trianglular number of 30 is 465
>   
>  The trianglular number of 35 is 630
>   
>  The trianglular number of 40 is 820
>   
>  The trianglular number of 45 is 1035
>   
>  The trianglular number of 50 is 1275

I don't understand why putting `TriNumber = ((n + 1) * n) / 2;` on its own line in the first code and within the `printf` function in the second code would have such different results.

Comment: The first snippet computes `TriNumber` ten times, and then prints it once. The `printf` is **not** in the loop.

Comment: `for` is the start of a loop.  The next _statement_ is repeated for as long as the loop condition is satisfied. Your first example, the print occurs _after_ the looping is finished. Your second example, the print is part of the loop.

Comment: Check your course notes. The only statement executed directly after that `for` loop statement is ...

Comment: You don't print anything until you are done the for loop in the first code.  Also then, the "n" variable has incremented one last time to 55.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `for` loop (or any other control structure, for that matter) without curly braces operates on one statement only. So the first snippet would loop over the `TriNumber` calculation, but only call `printf` once the loop is done. It's equivalent to writing

```
for(n = 5;  n <= 50; n += 5) {
    TriNumber = ((n + 1) * n) / 2;
}
printf("The trianglular number of %d is %d\n", n, TriNumber);
```

In order to get it to work as you expected, you could add the curly braces yourself, around both statements:

```
for(n = 5;  n <= 50; n += 5) {
    TriNumber = ((n + 1) * n) / 2;
    printf("The trianglular number of %d is %d\n", n, TriNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

● In your **first case**, the `for` loop computes the `TriNumber` till the condition satisfies and then moves onto the next statement; i.e, the `printf`:

```
for(n = 5;  n <= 50; n += 5)
    TriNumber = ((n + 1) * n) / 2;

printf("The trianglular number of %d is %d\n", n, TriNumber);
```

This is similar to *(for better understanding)*:

```
for(n = 5;  n <= 50; n += 5)
{
    TriNumber = ((n + 1) * n) / 2;
}
printf("The triangular number of %d is %d\n", n, TriNumber);
```

That's why you get a single statement output stating:

> The triangular number of 55 is 1275

● While in your **second case**, the `for` loop computes the `TriNumber` and prints it everytime as far as the loop condition is satisfied, since the `printf` here is the very next statement of the `for` loop that gets executed.

```
for(n = 5;  n <= 50; n += 5)

    printf("The trianglular number of %d is %d\n", n, TriNumber = (((n + 1) * n) / 2));
```

which is similar to the below code even without the braces `{}`:

```
for(n = 5;  n <= 50; n += 5)
{
    printf("The trianglular number of %d is %d\n", n, TriNumber = (((n + 1) * n) / 2));
}
```

This is valid for not only `for` loop but all other control structure like `while`, `if`;etc that operates on the very next statement without the `{}` braces as said by [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik).

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you print after last loop iteration and as result `n` get extra increment by `5` and you see `55`. In the second case you print right from last iteration and loop counter is not extra increased yet and you see `50`.